# Swift - how do i convert a regular XML file to a .plist XML file

Tags: ios, xml, swift, converters, plist

I searched the web for this one and mostly found Obj-C answers or outdated answers so ill simply post the question and hope for the best :)

Im working with a team of Android Developers while im working on IOS. they use XML files for a lot of data. since we want the data between us to stay consistent - we want to be able to have shared XML files to use in our projects.
I know **.plist** is basically a type of XML, but i want to be able to get the regular shared XML file and turn it into a .plist and then use it in my IOS project.

any known method of doing it at all? if so, is it possible to do it automatically somehow? (script or something of that sort. maybe even do it locally inside the application)

Thanks for the help

Comment: A .plist file is a very specific XML file with only a small set of keys allowed. A random XML file will not be convertible to a .plist file. Try converting to JSON first, if you can convert it to JSON you will be able to automatically convert it to a .plist after that.

Comment: thanks for the reply deadbeef. if thats the case, is there any downside at all to simply use the random XML file with an XML pasrser instead of the whole plist thing?

Comment: Well, XML is usually a pain to parse compared to JSON. But aside from that the difference should be minimal. You can try `NSXMLParser` if you want.

Comment: thanks deadbeef, can u post your first and second comment together as an answer and ill mark it as the right answer and upvote you? you deserve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .plist file is a very specific XML file with only a small set of keys allowed. A random XML file will not be convertible to a .plist file.

Try converting your file to JSON first. If you can convert it to JSON you will be able to automatically convert it to a .plist after that using the `plutil` command with the `xml1` or `binary1` format.

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o output.plist input.json
```

If you can't convert it to JSON, you can keep your XML file as is and parse it in your app using `NSXMLParser`. XML is harder to parse than .plist or JSON files, but aside from that the difference should be minimal.